# Remote Desktop through multiple ssh tunnels (A - B - C)

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, tunnel

I have 3 machines. Machine A which can access B, and B which can access C (which is a windows computer)

How can I connect with remote desktop directly from machine A to C with ssh tunnel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will only need *one* tunnel, since there is only one machine in the middle.

1. Connect from A to B using SSH, with a local tunnel from `:<portX>` to `<machineC>:3389`.

   Depending on your SSH client:

   - OpenSSH – `ssh -fN -L<portX>:<machineC>:3389 <machineB>`
   - PuTTY – source port `<portX>`, destination `<machineC>:3389`, type *local*.

     PuTTY also accepts the same `-L` option when run from command line.
2. Connect from A to `localhost:<portX>` using Remote Desktop.

   - Windows Remote Desktop – enter `localhost:<portX>` in the *Computer* box.

     Or run `mstsc /v localhost:<portX>`.

Here *`<portX>`* is any port between 1024-65535, and not yet in use by machine A.