# Forward VNC traffic through a middle machine

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, tunnel

I have 3 machines..

- A. My local machine at home (MacOSX).
- B. Machine at work that I can SSH into (middle man). It is a small virtual machine running Ubuntu server and I can open new ports
- C. Another machine at work running Ubuntu Desktop with vine for remote desktop access I can access this machine with SSH via B.

So I can SSH from A -> B and from B I can see open ports in C. I want to access C using a VNC client.

Is there a way to setup a tunnel from A to C through B?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer https://superuser.com/a/371082/281372, here's what you need to do specifically:

```
user@machineA $ ssh -fN -L59595:machineC:59595 user@machineB \
                -c 'ssh -fN -L59595:machineB:5900 user@machineC' &

user@machineA $ vncviewer localhost:59595
```

This opens a ssh session from A to B with a tunnel from A:59595 to B:59595; and in the ssh session on B, it opens a new ssh session from B to C with a tunnel from B:59595 to C:5900.

Then back on A, you vnc to localhost:59595. It is tunneled to B:59595, which then catches it and retunnels it to C:5900.

I have not tested it.

(In a previous answer I recommended socat and netcat, but it's clear now you want the whole tunnel protected by ssh.)

Comment: Thx, I hava tested your vnc and ssh answers, but seems like VNC uses a slightly more complex protocol since I reach the computer, send the password but the connection doe s not progress anymore